# IPsec on multicast

Tags: linux, ipsec

I am trying to implement IPSec for multicast communication, I tried [strongSwan](http://strongswan.org/) for setting up IPSec for unicast but it doesn't support any standard for multicast ipsec as listed here https://wiki.strongswan.org/projects/strongswan/wiki/IpsecStandards.

I successfully implemented IPSec for multicast using iproute2 tool using the following commands and configurations

[image]

For sender (192.168.1.3)

```
ip xfrm state flush; ip xfrm policy flush

ip xfrm state add src 192.168.1.3 dst 232.1.1.1 proto esp spi 0x54c1859e mode tunnel reqid 0x67cea4aa  auth sha256 0xc8a8bf5ce6330699c3500bd8d2637bc1fa26929bab747d5ff2a1c4dddc7ce7ff enc aes 0xfdce8eaf81e3da02fa67e07df975c0111ecfa906561e762e5f3e78dfe106498e

ip xfrm policy add src 192.168.1.3 dst 232.1.1.1 dir out tmpl src 192.168.1.3 dst 232.1.1.1 proto esp reqid 0x67cea4aa mode tunnel
```

and for receivers (192.168.1.1 and 192.168.1.2)

```
ip xfrm state flush; ip xfrm policy flush

ip xfrm state add src 192.168.1.3 dst 232.1.1.1 proto esp spi 0x54c1859e mode tunnel reqid 0x67cea4aa  auth sha256 0xc8a8bf5ce6330699c3500bd8d2637bc1fa26929bab747d5ff2a1c4dddc7ce7ff enc aes 0xfdce8eaf81e3da02fa67e07df975c0111ecfa906561e762e5f3e78dfe106498e

ip xfrm policy add src 192.168.1.3 dst 232.1.1.1 dir in tmpl src 192.168.1.3 dst 232.1.1.1 proto esp reqid 0x67cea4aa mode tunnel
```

This successfully created IPSec tunnel for multicast group 232.1.1.1, but the issue is I am using manual keying mechanism. Is there any tool or way around to setup group SA and group policies and refresh keys after certain interval ?

Comment: For key management you might want to check out [Multicast Security (MSEC)](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4046)

Comment: @raz: I really appreciate your response but with all due respect I know this RFC and if you take a look at the link I shared, for IPSec Standards implemented in strongSwan, contains these RFCs. I wanted to know if there is any tool or implementation available to for setting group SA or group keying.

Comment: According to the link you provided strongSwan is an implementation that contains MSEC which can setup group SAs and rekeying.  Are you asking how to use strongSwan to set these settings up?

Comment: No, MSEC is not supported in strongSwan. I am looking for tools or open source implementations which can do MSEC, GSAKMP, GDOI or GKDP in scenarios such as elaborated in the question.

Comment: Natually that column I completely ignored was important, my apologies.  The only implemenation of GSAKMP/MSEC that seems to be available is [gsakmp](http://gsakmp.sourceforge.net/).  And it's not even clear if this is a full implementation or not... pretty old, designed for Java 1.4.  Seems like no one is working on this which is surprising with the rise (kind of) of IPv6 and the Internet of Things.

Comment: @raz thank you, I will check if it works though the source code seems to be 12 years old.

Comment: @raz IPsec was very rarely even on the table in the IoT projects I've been involved in. Not popular to say the least...

Answer (score 1):

Cisco and Juniper routers implement GDOI.

Also you can look at this implementation: [GDOI Reference Implementation Primer](http://mirror.unpad.ac.id/orari/library/library-sw-hw/linux-1/sip/vocal/source/gdoi/), but it's a bit old.

Comment: +1 for the link, have you tried this implementation. I am trying to compile it and it is a road full of blocks.

Answer (score 0):

I found a question and answer related to keys and group policy here [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/questions/426246/ssh-does-not-allow-the-use-of-a-key-with-group-readable-permissionsf).

Also, the code listed at the link is:
    edit the Sudo User With:

```
%AccessGroup ALL=(git-sync) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/"Access"
```

and edit the hook with:

```
sudo -u git-sync /usr/bin/"AccessGroup" push origin
```

There are also the commands:

```
#!/usr/sbin/setkey -f
#
# SPD for gateway A (172.16.72.1)
#
spdadd 192.168.1.0/24 10.42.23.0/24 any -P out ipsec
       esp/tunnel/172.16.72.1-172.16.72.254/require
       ah/tunnel/172.16.72.1-172.16.72.254/require;
spdadd 10.42.23.0/24 192.168.1.0/24 any -P in ipsec
        esp/tunnel/172.16.72.254-172.16.72.1/require
        ah/tunnel/172.16.72.254-172.16.72.1/require;
    # AH SAD entries with 160 bit keys
add 172.16.72.254 172.16.72.1 ah 0x200 -A hmac-sha1         0x46915c30ed7e2465b42861b6ab19f2772813020c;
add 172.16.72.1 172.16.72.254 ah 0x300 -A hmac-sha1 0xc4dac594f8228e0b94a54758f7fbf2fdf4e37f3e;
```

## ESP SAD entries with 192 bit keys

```
add 172.16.72.254 172.16.72.1 esp 0x201 -E rijndael-cbc      0xa3993b3dfc41ef0a1aa8d168a8bf2c27e48249ac17b61e09;
add 172.16.72.1 172.16.72.254 esp 0x301 -E rijndael-cbc 0x8f6498928ba354bd45cfad147f54c67b3b742896b3bafc02;
```

this needs to be modified, of course ([source](http://linuxgazette.net/126/pfeiffer.html))

As far as refreshing keys, the following script might help:

auto

what operation, if any, should be done automatically at IPsec startup; currently-accepted values are

```
 add (signifying an ipsec auto --add), 
route (signifying that plus an ipsec auto --route), 
start (signifying that plus an ipsec auto --up), 
manual (signifying an ipsec manual --up), 
and ignore (also the default) (signifying no automatic startup operation).
```

Relevant only locally, other end need not agree on it (but in general, for an intended-to-be-permanent connection, both ends should use auto=start to ensure that any reboot causes immediate renegotiation).

[source](http://linux.die.net/man/5/ipsec.conf)

I wrote the start of a python script to help distribute and group client keys:
The code is still being worked on though...

```
    void key (str x)
def _init_(key, status):  
class key:
key.status = status
#Getter function
@status
def status(key):
return key.status
#Setter Function
    @status.setter
    def status(key, value):
    if not isinstance(value, str):
    raise TypeError('Expected Key Not Found')
    key.status = value

#Deleter function
 @status.deleter
 def status(key):
 raise AttibuteError("Can't Delete Attribute")
 from operator import itemgetter
 from ittertools import groupby
 rows.sort(key=itemgetter(key.status))
for key.status, items in groupby(rows, key=itemgetter(key.status)):
print(status)
for i in items:
print(' ', i)
#Asserting Keys to Subclasses
class key(group)
    @key
    def status(key):
    print("Adding Key to Group")
    return super().status
 @status.setter
 def name(status, value):
print('Distributing Keys', value)
super(Subclient, Subclient).status._set_(key, value)
    @key.deleter
    def status(key):
    print('Revoking Key')
    super(Subclient, Subclient).key._delete_(status)
```

This is not entered at the terminal, but run as a script!